# virtualenv on OSX 10.8. Issue with install_name_tool

Tags: virtualenv, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to run virtualenv on OSX 10.8 and but I'm getting the following error

```
aidan$ virtualenv --distribute bbhq
New python executable in bbhq/bin/python
Usage: install_name_tool [-change old new] ... [-rpath old new] ... [-add_rpath new] ... [-delete_rpath old] ... [-id name] input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1029, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1321, in install_python
    install_name_tool = get_install_name_tool()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1559, in get_install_name_tool
    raise ValueError("your version of OSX wasn't planned for.  "
ValueError: your version of OSX wasn't planned for.  File a bug against:  https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/168
```

I'm struggling to make sense of what's going on here. I've got Xcode installed (along with the command line tools) and I can see install_name_tool at `/usr/bin/install_name_tool`. I installed virtual env using easy_install (and that seemed to go fine).

virtualenv is creating the directory and some files. But it hasn't worked properly - there's no activate script in there.

Any ideas what's going on here? (it looks a lot like virtualenv simply doesn't work on osx 10.8).

Comment: so yes, virtualenv doesn't work yet with mountain lion. what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I never worked out what was causing the problem. I uninstalled virtualenv `sudo pip uninstall virtualenv`, then reinstalled it again `sudo pip install virtualenv`. And that fixed everything. virtualenv works as expected without the errors above.

It looks like there's quite a few people who've had issues (normally when upgrading to Mountain Lion), and there's a few people blogging about the process of setting it up. Googling 'virtualenv "mountain lion"' brought up lots of stuff.